# Converting from Money class to Int Fails

Tags: c++, class, templates

Compilation error is:
 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'Money'
File: genericarray.h
Line: 13

This is my main function

```
int main()
{
    genericArray<Money>m3(5);
    Money d(-1, 89);
    Money a(10, 5);
    Money b(10, 5);
    Money c(43, 7);
    Money k(50, 6);
    Money m(10, 20);
    Money bonus(5, 0);

    m3.elements[0] = a;
    m3.elements[1] = b;
    m3.elements[2] = c;
    m3.elements[3] = k;
    m3.elements[4] = m;

    m3.total = m3.sum();
    m2.total = m2.sum();
    m1.total = m1.sum();

    return 0;
}
```

This is my Assignment operator overloading of Money class and Money class itself

```
class Money
{
private:
    int lira;
    int kurus;
public:
    Money() { lira = 0; kurus = 0; }
    Money(int a, int b);
    ~Money() {}
    void operator=(const Money& money2) { this->lira = money2.lira; this->kurus = money2.kurus; }
    void operator=(int l) { this->lira = l; this->kurus = 0; }
```

This is my genericArray class with sum() function

```
template <class Type> 
class genericArray
{
private:
int size;
public:
Type* elements;
Type total;
Type sum()
{
    Type sumAll = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sumAll += elements[i];
    }
    if (sumAll > 100)
        sumAll += 5;
    return sumAll;
}
genericArray() { elements = NULL; size = 0; }
genericArray(int arrSize) { elements = new Type[arrSize]; size = arrSize; }
~genericArray() { delete[] elements; }
};
```

Comment: You have two unrelated questions. One of them can be closed immediately as a duplicate. The other needs to be extended upon. So one question per question please.

Comment: "*Where the error occurs*" - What error?

Comment: Converting from Money class to Int Fails
its on the title, so i didnt think i need to rewrite it

Comment: @Tunti I don't think that's the actual error message. For one, the file name and line number are missing. Also, there is no `Int` type (there's no `Money` class in your code either, actually).

Comment: Now, welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), read e.g. [this SO question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And don't forget to tell us the actual error message you get. In full, complete, and copy-pasted as text (and mark the exact line of it).

Comment: @melpomene when i create genericArray consists of Money class, the sum() function has an assignment operator on the first line of the function which is trying to assign "0" to the Money class. So, i overloaded the assignment operator such that it assigns the value to the "int lira" private method and make "int kurus" 0. The problem is on the compilation, it gives the error i mentioned. The line is at the "Type sumAll = 0;"

Comment: @Tunti You're still paraphrasing. Don't describe the code, show us the code. Don't describe the error, show us the error message! In short, post a [mcve].

Comment: If you found a solution, _post an answer_. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i edited with the solution, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @Tunti: And I rolled it back again. **If you found a solution, _post an answer_.** Only the question goes in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a new  constructor with a single int parameter solved the problem:

```
Money(const int a) 
{
    if (a < 0) throw "The amount of money can not be below zero!";
    this->lira = a; 
    this->kurus = 0; 
}
```

The point is that

```
Type sumAll = 0;
```

calls only the constructor which takes only 1 int instead of calling the default constructor and the assignment operator.

Comment: Accept your answer (click check mark under reputation cout)